# Rounding down a float to nearest 0.5 in Objective C / Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch

I want to round a floating point number down such that I get that will be anywhere between 0.5 and 7 (with any number of decimals) while rounding anything below 0.5 up to 0.5.

For example,

```
0.1, 0.11442, 0.46 would all be 0.5.
1.1, 1.43, 1.35 would all be 1.
1.56, 1.6, 1.8 would all be 1.5.
```

Anything over 5 will be rounded down to 5.

The final data set I want is `0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5`.

I don't know any functions that round down for `Objective C`, without it being to whole numbers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`floor()` will round down floating point numbers to the next integer. If you first multiply by 2, round down, then divide by two, you will get the desired result.

```
float rounded = value < 0.5f ? 0.5f : floorf(value * 2) / 2;
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is spot on.  Your second, not so much.  `floorf` is *really* cheap (cheaper than 7 comparisons on average).

Comment: You're right. But I wasn't concerned about the rounding operation, but the additional floating point OPs. However I run a performance test, and my first simple suggestion is about twice as fast.

Comment: for negative numbers, you can call ABS() before and after the round, move the result to negativ

Answer (score 0):

To "round to nearest" interval, add half the interval and truncate to an interval boundary.

For rounding to nearest int that's `(int) (value + 0.5)` but it's a hair trickier with 0.5 boundaries -- the adding half the interval is easy, but the truncate to an 0.5 boundary isn't.

So the most practical approach is to double the number, round to an int boundary, then divide by 2.

Another way to do it is to separate the integer and fraction parts (`fraction = value - (int) value;`) and then use a simple "if ladder" to format the fraction part separately.  (Beware -- negative numbers can be a hair tricky.)  This might be a better choice if you need to round to some irregular set of boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

first comment was good, but it skips zeros and negative values.. my 5 cents:

```
float roundToHalf (float val)
{
    if (val==0) return 0;
    int sign = fabs(val)/val;
    return sign * (fabs(val) < 0.5f ? 0.5f : floorf(fabs(val)) * 2 / 2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I noticed that determining the sign by dividing (as shown here) is bullshit because of floating point algebra. Also it is slow on many systems.

```
float round_half_f(float val) {
  short sign = (short)(val / fabs(val) );
  return floorf(fabs(val)*2.f) / 2.f * sign;
}
```

Do this:

```
float round_half_f(float val) {
  short sign = val < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  return floorf(fabs(val)*2.f) / 2.f * sign;
}
```